# Find and replace text in columns between sheets in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in column C of sheet 1 and have numeric accreditations related to C in B of sheet 2. Now i need to search all the data of B in sheet 2 in C of sheet 1 and replace them with numeric accreditations.

Example:
Sheet 1:

```
  A            |  B    |   C  |     D
 --------------|-------|------|-----------
  kilometers   | 125   |  km  |  quantity
  kilometers   | 1000  |  km  |  quantity
  kilograms    | 1000  |  kg  |  quantity
  kilometers   | 1000  |  km  |  quantity
  kilograms    | 155   |  kg  |  quantity
```

Sheet 2:

```
     A     |    B
    -------|-------        
     1     |    dz
     2     |    km
     3     |    kg
     4     |    ltr
```

Desired output:

Sheet 1:

```
     A       |   B    |   C   |     D
  -----------|--------|-------|-----------
  kilometers |  125   |   2   |  quantity
  kilometers |  1000  |   2   |  quantity
  kilograms  |  1000  |   3   |  quantity
  kilometers |  1000  |   2   |  quantity
  kilograms  |  155   |   3   |  quantity
```

I have such data in half million on 800 different variants in sheet 2, need to find each and replace in sheet 1.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: So what have you tried? SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you can use `Index/Match`.

You'll need to insert an extra column in your sheet, which you can fill, paste values, and then delete the original column.

Insert a new column, so you have an empty Column D, and put this in the second row:
`=Index(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,Match($C2,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5,0))`

Basically, you want to return the index that has the numbers in your sheet2.

Alternatively, you could write some If statement with `Substitute($C2,"km","2")`